# Laravel - Implicit route model binding with soft deleted data

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I am having a small issue. There are two user roles and one is a normal member and one is an admin. The member can delete a blog and they will not be able to see the blog after they delete (soft delete) it while the admin can still see the blog, even if it's soft deleted.

Example code:

```
// Route file
Route::get('/blog/{blog}', 'BlogController@show');

// BlogController 

public function show(App\Blog $blog) {
    // It never gets to here if the blog has been soft deleted... 
    // Automatically throws an 404 exception
}
```

I want the admin to be able to visit the blog even if it's soft deleted but it doesn't really work. I am trying to edit the route service provider but I haven't gotten any luck as it doesn't let me use the `Auth::user()` function to get the logged in user so I can check if they have permission.

My `RouteServiceProvider`

```
  $router->bind('post', function($post) {
        if (Auth::user()->isAdmin()
            return Post::withTrashed()->where('id', $post)->firstOrFail();
    });
```

This does not work as it doesn't know what `Auth::user()` is. I have imported `Auth` facade but still doesn't work.

Edit: It gives me a `null` value when I dump and die `Auth::user()`.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What does "it doesn't let me" mean? Error message, ... ?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. But it just says null and says cannot check the function on null..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found out that getting the `current logged in user` is not possible in Route Service Provider because it loads before all session service provider.

Instead I simply did:

```
//Route Service Provider
 $router->bind('post', function($post)
     return Post::withTrashed()->where('id', $post)->firstOrFail();
});

// Controller
public function show(Post $post) {

// If the post has been trashed and the user is not admin, he cannot see it
     if (!Auth::user()->isAdmin() && $post->trashed())
         abort(404);

     // Proceed with normal request because the post has not been deleted.
}
```

Answer (score 13):

As this question pop ups when googling for this, in newer Laravel versions you can do this:

```
Route::get('posts/{post}', [PostController::class, 'show'])->withTrashed();
```

See: [Implicit Soft Deleted Models](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#implicit-soft-deleted-models)

Comment: How does this check to include trashed models if the user is authorised?